# Remove right border off of the last Child div through CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have right border with my child divs but I want to remove the right border from the last div.

### Here is the HTML

```
         <div class="nav-footer">

            <div class="col-lg-2">
              <h2 class="light-blue">Who</h2>
              <p class="white">are the people/ would you drink with</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
              <h2 class="light-blue">Where</h2>
              <p class="white">would be having a hangover</p>
           </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
              <h2 class="light-blue">What</h2>
              <p class="white">would you be working on</p>
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-2">
              <h2 class="light-blue">How</h2>
              <p class="white">does a team drink</p>
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-2">
              <h2 class="light-blue">Why</h2>
              <p class="white">should you drink</p>
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-2">
              <h2 class="light-blue">Show</h2>
              <p class="white">at Vegas</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

### CSS

```
.nav-footer .col-lg-2       { border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;}
.nav-footer .col-lg-2 .last { border-right:none; }
```

It doesn't work like that ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you meant to use the  `:last-child` selector:

```
.nav-footer .col-lg-2:last-child
```

[**jsFiddle example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4s6QK/)

Comment: strange. It works in the JSFiddle but doesn't work in my case.

Comment: there was clear:both at the end of the div, that's why it didn't work. When I removed that, it worked.