# Remove last li border

Tags: html, css

I am not very pr in css How do i remove border-bottom from only the last li element in css.

```
ul li{
   border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo-class:

```css
ul li:last-child {
   border-bottom: 0;
}
```

This only works in IE9+. As a workaround, you could give top border to the list items and override the value for the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child):

```css
ul li {
   border-top: 1px solid blue;
}

ul li:first-child {
   border-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
ul li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use + [Adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) for adding `border`

```css
ul li+li {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go thru this link and see if this could help [Remove right border off of the last Child div through CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525307/remove-right-border-off-of-the-last-child-div-through-css)

Also

```
ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```